# Schematic "shared/services/lessons" not found in collection "@schematics/angular"

Tags: angular, angular-cli

when i try to create a Service with this command `ng g shared/services/lessons -d`,
it always throws me this exception: `Schematic "shared/services/lessons" not found in collection "@schematics/angular".`

I've already reinstalled node_modules, with the same result.

`ng --version` shows me this:

```html
Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.901.7
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.901.7
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.901.7
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.901.7
@angular-devkit/core              9.1.7
@angular-devkit/schematics        9.1.7
@angular/cdk                      9.2.4
@angular/cli                      9.1.7
@angular/material                 9.2.4
@ngtools/webpack                  9.1.7
@schematics/angular               11.2.2
@schematics/update                0.901.7
rxjs                              6.5.5
typescript                        3.8.3
webpack                           4.42.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are missing a third argument, the schematics to provid.

`ng g <schematic> shared/services/lessons -d`

In case of wanting a service, you should use the schematic `service` or `s`.

You can find all the schematics and their options [here](https://angular.io/cli/generate).